# AS3: possible to dynamically attach things without linkage id?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Probably a stupid question but..
Is it possible to dynamically add things to the stage using code WITHOUT having manually checked "export for actionscript" for each item, and without having given linkage id's?

I make pages upon pages of "drag and drop" items for people to drag around.. and it just gets unfathomably time consuming to first manually give each item an instance name, then "view in library" for each item one at a time, then modding its Properties, then checking off the box and giving each a linkageID, keeping track of the number etc.  Seems like there *must* be a better/faster way?

In my case, the items are *always* on the stage to begin with, so I *know* that they are being exported in the swf, even without having checked off the box...

Oh hey.. since I'm starting with the item in question when the user clicks it, could they instead "duplicate" the item they clicked on?  I think this was possible in AS2?  Would that still require a linkage id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can just look through the display chain if you know that an item is already on the stage. What you get back will be a [`DisplayObject`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html) and you'll have to decide if it's a `MovieClip` or a `Sprite` but it can be done. You can name movie clips on the stage and find them by name, too - these don't need to be exported for scripting.

All `DisplayObject` instances have a `name` property and you can use [`getChildByName`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObjectContainer.html#getChildByName()) to find a named instance at run-time.

You only need to export a symbol for scripting if you want to control the base type of the symbol (so you can add extra properties / methods to it) or if you want to programmatically create new instances of a symbol during run-time. Anything that's on the stage (or inside a display object container on the Stage) can be accessed through an index (not recommended) or through a name and don't need to be exported.

You cannot programmatically create instances of display objects without exporting them first.

Comment: Yeah, I'm already using getChildByName to give eventListeners to all the items, and I know how to get the name.  But the problem I have is just, how do I write that one line that creates the new object, using the name?  I'm so lost on this..  I was just trying this, looked promising, but still seems to be looking for the linkage name.. var TestClass:Object = getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(e.currentTarget)) as Class;

Comment: " or if you want to programmatically create new instances of a symbol during run-time".. yeah, essentially that is still what I'm trying to do.  So it's probably not possible then?

Comment: ..or is at least possible to mass-add linkage ID's?  It just takes SO long to add them one by one to HUNDREDS of movieclips, and to give them matching instance names.. I'm tired lol...  I've been doing this for years this way and it's a waste of life...

Comment: If you're trying to create _new instances_ of symbols, those must be exported to the library - there's no other way. There are some tools that claim to be able to clone objects already on the stage but it's just easier to export the clip and then create a new instance when needed. You get much more control that way over creating instances.

Comment: If you export things to the library, you don't need to give anything instance names - you can just load everything from code and then position them on the stage at run-time. I haven't used instance names for years and usually my stage is empty. I load everything at run-time from exported symbols.

Comment: If you put clips on the stage, you need instance names because that's the only reliable way to hook up to them at run-time - that's a chore and it's tiresome. If you start with an empty stage, you can just writte a few lines of code to load an exported symbol and then you don't need names anymore - your local / class variables will hold references to the right display objects.

Comment: Oh okay.. not giving things instance names saves half the battle I guess.  What happens though is there's an item on the stage, the user clicks on it, and a copy gets added to the stage, that they drag.  So, how do I go from the on-stage instance, to communicating with the library?  I used to use code that split/joined from the instance name to find the matching linkage id in the library.  How else would I code it to know which item to add?  How do I get the code to get the linkage id of the item that's being clicked on?

Comment: Please post a separate question for that - comments are not a very good place for extended discussion.

Comment: It's okay.. I got it to work. var objectClass:Class = Object(e.currentTarget).constructor;   But if you want to edit your original answer to say that essentially it's not possible, I can upvote it =)

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. I won't update the answer since it's possible to do so (you just did it), although I don't think it's a very clean solution. You'll likely save a bit of typing but will run into maintenance issues with your projects later on. If you need to create instances, I'd recommend just exporting them (or using Flash Develop and do everything from code - it's a _lot_ simpler that way).

Comment: No no.. all I got working is adding the objects without having to use instance names.  I still had to give them linkage IDs unfortunately.  It still sucks, although I discovered that in Flash CC I can select multiple items in the library and give them linkage id's all at once, which helps a little (although a lot of my items aren't neatly stacked in the library like that, oh well).  It seems the items still do have to be checked off for export to be added dynamically, as you originally said =(

Comment: Ah ok, I misunderstood. I'd seriously recommend using FlashDevelop. I used to use Flash but it's a terribly inadequate environment for coding. It's ok for making artwork (still buggy) but for coding, it's a lot less headache to use FlashDevelop, once you get up to speed with it.

Comment: I deal with a lot of very high quality artwork, sometimes importing from Photoshop, sometimes from Illustrator, and sometimes created natively, so it's #flash4life for me lol ;)

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. I work on (hobby) games and also deal with a lot of artwork (probably less than you do) but I find resource handling much easier in FlashDevelop.